# Want to simulate a mechanism with spring in it for forces acting in different direction (Kinematics). How to do it using solidworks or ANSYS?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, mechanisms, solidworks, solid-mechanics

Thought of using motion study in  Solidworks but not able to account for forces at the different axis in it

here is the image to better understand it. There hasn't been any progress with the simulation though, I am still confused about where to start with

[image]

Comment: A diagram of what you want to simulate and the progress of the model so far may help understand your issues.

Comment: Sure @SolarMike updated !

Comment: Is there any reason you can't prototype this? Simulation is great, but for something both simple, and 'springy', like this, it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can create planes perpendicular to any axis or parallel to any surface. if the surface is not flat as in your case these planes can then be used to apply forces of different types in motion study
basically you need to know how to create planes on those curved surfaces and apply forces on them in motion study

Comment: Ohh ok, will try this, also how should I go with the springs?  the two springs at the back are compression springs and in the front, there is a lever of a limit switch

Comment: you can simulate the action of springs between two surfaces in motion study. they're  various options available for whatever spring specs you need. Take some lessons on motion study to have an idea of what is possible but as for your lever, that will have to be modelled